How to track open database connections with Entity Framework Core 8?
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application. In production the application throws an error

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 08P01: no more connections allowed (max_client_conn)

I am using NPGSQL and Entity Framework Core.
I am trying to diagnose if there is a leaky connection not being closed. Everywhere I have found is using dependency injection to handle getting the databaseContext.
Is there a way to get a list of database connections from Entity Framework Core so I can track when one is being opened and when that same connection is being closed?
I have tried using logTo() which can log when a DB connection is opened or closed but that does not say when which connection is closed or what the context is for the connection being opened.
I have also tried using DiagnosticListeners to see when connections are opened but that does not give any more information that the logTo() method.

Probably you have to find slow query, Usually such symptons are related not optimized controller.

How many active sessions is your database serving at a time? Are you using a connection pool manager like PgBouncer? When building web applications, a key chokepoint consideration is database connections. Web servers, especially with async processing can handle many concurrent requests where depending on your EF config and how you are scoping DbContexts, reserve connections. PostgreSQL will default to 100 concurrent connections and servers can easily exceed 100 concurrent requests. Requests will wait, but only so long so query speed and idle monitoring is a high priority.

Look at your database through a profiler and see what kinds of queries the site is executing over a short window of normal use, then check the running time of those queries. Also, if you have diagnostics built into the app look to capture the running time for requests. This will be problematic if your views are rendering based on entities since the context will be open longer than the method execution. Look at the browser network stats for page visits and request times, The longer these are, the longer connections will be reserved.
